# Generating data matrix from a ZIP string in Java

Tags: java, zxing

I'm trying to generate a data matrix from a zip string using Zxing in Java and the result is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Message contains characters outside ISO-8859-1 encoding.

The code is:

```
byte[] bytesOfZIP= (byte[])statD.returnObj; // here is the zipped content
String texto = new String(bytesOfZIP, "UTF8");
DataMatrixWriter barcodeWriter = new DataMatrixWriter();
BitMatrix bitMatrix = barcodeWriter.encode(texto, BarcodeFormat.DATA_MATRIX, 400, 400);// exception appears at this line
BufferedImage bi = MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage(bitMatrix);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", baos);
byte[] fbytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

I'm looking for any solution to encode a ZIP file with these special chars not necessarily with Zxing.

Comment: `new String(bytesOfZIP, "UTF8");` is **wrong** and will not do what you want. In fact trying to treat any binary data (such as the content of a ZIP file) as text is misleading and wrong. Most barcode formats are designed to store either simple numbers or text. You'll have to find one that can handle arbitrary binary data *or* encode your binary data using Base64 (which will increase the size by about 33%, which is especially bad for barcodes).

Comment: Can you please explain what the high-level goal is you're trying to achieve, because I think this is a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). There are many problems with your approach: 1. ZIP files have headers which increase the size of your QR code which is probably something you want to avoid. 2. bar codes are not built for arbitrary binary data, they tend to encode stuff in textual data (and that's what most APIs are built to support). 3. your storing a bar code as JPEG which is a lossy format and definitely suboptimal. PNG files will be smaller *and* encode the image more faithfully.

Comment: Joachim, I'm just implementing the specifications I received where I must generate an XML, zip it and encode it with data matrix. It's a governmental specification for electronic prescriptions. The data matrix code will be used to automatically import the encoded data. ZIP is required as the data volume can be big for a barcode.

Comment: Wow, I'm sorry for your pain on that one. But on the up-side, they *probably* define how to put binary data into a format meant for text, so that should help. You could *try* pretending your binary data is ISO-8859-1 (which would also be wrong, but wrong in a slightly different way that might pass the relevant checks). In other words, replace the `UTF8` in your code with `ISO-8859-1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Not an answer***

There are some problems, hence in answer form.

```
byte[] bytesOfZIP = (byte[])statD.returnObj; // here is the zipped content
```

An `Object` (or `char[]`, or `String`) cannot be case to a `byte[]` array.

```
String texto = new String(bytesOfZIP, "UTF8");
```

This will compile but the official name is `"UTF-8"` and as already mentioned, `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` would be nicer (no `UnsupportedEncodingException` as UTF-8m is standard, always available). However `bytesOfZIP` are never UTF-8 text, which requires a special format. In fact binary data should never be pressed in String with 2 byte chars. It requires twice a conversion to Unicode, double memory, and is almost certain to be corrupted.

```
DataMatrixWriter barcodeWriter = new DataMatrixWriter();
BitMatrix bitMatrix = barcodeWriter.encode(texto, BarcodeFormat.DATA_MATRIX, 400, 400);

BufferedImage bi = MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage(bitMatrix);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", baos);
byte[] fbytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

JPEG (.jpg, .jpeg) is a lossy compression. For a black-and-white barcode try use png.

***Solution***

Unzipping should first check the format: a `test.txt.gz` would use a `GZipInputStream`. A `test.zip` a ZipFile, a ZipInputStream, or copying from zip file system. These are standard classes to be found in the internet.

As the contents are probably pure text, you can first try it hard-coded after manually unzipping.

If you start with a `byte[]` then the matrix printer probably requires MS Latin 1, or `Charset.fromName("Windows-1252")`. Latin-1, ISO-8859-1 or `StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1` has a forbidden control range from `\u0080 - \u00BF`.

Comment: I used ISO-8859-1 as suggested and it looks fine, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You should try to replace "UTF8" with "StandardCharsets.UTF_8". Because I don't think "UTF8" is the correct way to set the charset of the string.

Comment: That's the least of the problems in this code and if it was causing problems, then the exception would be an `UnsupportedEncodingException`.